# My minecraft server running on a ubuntu VPS keeps crashing because "/start.sh" doesn't exist?

Tags: ubuntu, server, minecraft, vps

I'm running Spigot 1.9.2 on a VPS with Ubuntu. Randomly before I got this error in the terminal and the server shutdown after about 10 seconds.

```
[06:28:22 INFO]: Startup script './start.sh' does not exist! Stopping server.
```

it didn't generate a crash report or anything either...

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by not having a startup scripting for your server jar file. To do this you just have to create a script in the server folder and call it start.sh. In it you write:

cd /path/to/server/folder 
 java -Xmx4G -jar ServerFile.jar

In which /path/to/server/folder is the path to the folder in which your server file is, the 4 in Xmx4G should be substituted by the number of GB of RAM it is allowed to use and ServerFile.jar is the file which is the server.

Excuse my formatting but I'm on my mobile device.

In best regards 
Nova

Comment: Thanks heaps Nova! Appreciate the reply. I'll give it a shot during my lunch break

Answer (score 0):

Find this code in the Spigot.ylm config file:

```
  restart-on-crash: true
       restart-script: ./start.sh
```

replace with this:

```
  restart-on-crash: false
       restart-script: ./start.sh
```